# Media Player Playback of mov fails

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm uploading mov files selected with the uiimagepickercontroller to my amazon s3 bucket but when I then try to play them with the media player framework, I'm told it's an invalid format.

Here's one: http://s3.amazonaws.com/irovr/users/9/92f7acd7-31b5-437c-8a30-16630e869d29/DEEDBFAE-8D41-4B52-B223-AA03B3A25491.mov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.  For anyone out there that's curious, don't gzip mov files when uploading to S3.  Images can be gzipped fine, but not mov.